# get value from another class c++

Tags: c++, constructor

Hello I have a getter in adjacencyMatrix class

```
int AdjacencyMatrix::getVertexFirst() const {   return vertexFirst; }
```

and constructor

```
AdjacencyMatrix::AdjacencyMatrix() {
    this->vertexCount=0;
    this->vertexFirst=0;
    this->edgeCount=0;
    this->matrix=0;
    this->wage=0;

}

bool AdjacencyMatrix::createFromFile(string path) {
    fstream file;
    file.open(path.c_str(), fstream::in);
    if (file.good())
    {
        int vertexF,vertexE,wag;            
        file >> this->edgeCount;
        file >> this->vertexCount;
        file >> this->vertexFirst;      

        matrix = new int *[vertexCount];
        wage   = new int *[vertexCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        {
            matrix[i]=new int[vertexCount];
            wage[i]=new int[vertexCount];
        }

        //fill matrix by zeros
        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        {

            for(int j=0; j<vertexCount;j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j]=0;
                wage[i][j]=0;

            }

        }  

        // fill matrix by 1

        for(int i=0; i<edgeCount; i++)
        {
            file >> vertexF >> vertexE >> wag;
            this->matrix[vertexF][vertexE]=1;
            this->wage[vertexF][vertexE]=wag;

        }    
        file.close();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

of course print works in Adjacency class
And now I want to have this value in Dijkstra class

```
//Dijkstra.cpp    
#include "Dijkstra.h" 
AdjacencyMatrix am;

bool Dijkstra::makeDijkstraAlgo() {     
    int vertexCount=am.getVertexCount();    
    int vertexFirst=am.getVertexFirst();
    int **wage=am.getWage();    
    cout << vertexCount;    
    cout << vertexFirst;
 .......... }
```

this is my main class

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dijkstra.h"
#include "Screen.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    AdjacencyMatrix am; 
    Dijkstra dijkstra;

    am.createFromFile("matrix.txt");
    dijkstra.makeDijkstraAlgo();
    dijkstra.viewDijkstra();
    return 0;
}
```

and this cout show only 0, but in AdjacencyMatrix show normal value. Can you help me ?

**UPDATE**

I notice that always will be 0 because I initialized value in constructor....
So How to make something like this

I create a matrix from file and add value to vertexCount etc.

```
am.createFromFile("matrix.txt");
```

now I want to get this value(vertexCount etc.) from adjacency matrix class to Dijkstry class and make

```
dijkstra.makeDijkstraAlgo();
dijkstra.viewDijkstra();
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Why would you expect `cout` to print something else? `vertexCount` is initialized to 0 and `cout` prints just that

Comment: Can we get more code? Make sure you properly initialize the values because from your code here `0` would actually be the expected result

Comment: @LahiruChandima you have right. Because I initialize a zero value in my constructor so every call will 0 it. But how to sovle it ? Just delete it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating one matrix but using another.

`makeDijkstraAlgo` uses the global matrix called ”am”, but `main` has its own matrix by the same name.

Get rid of the global and pass `main`'s matrix to the function

```
bool Dijkstra::makeDijkstraAlgo(const AdjacencyMatrix& am) {     
    int vertexCount=am.getVertexCount();    
    int vertexFirst=am.getVertexFirst();
    int **wage=am.getWage();    
    cout << vertexCount;    
    cout << vertexFirst;
    // ...
}

int main() {
    AdjacencyMatrix am; 
    Dijkstra dijkstra;

    am.createFromFile("matrix.txt");
    dijkstra.makeDijkstraAlgo(am);
    dijkstra.viewDijkstra();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah you have right. Next time i will more think ;)
Thank you so much ;)